# Col-xs-11 next to Col-xs-1 is wrapping to next line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having an issue with Bootstrap 3, where a col-xs-11 containing an address is getting wrapped underneath a col-xs-1 containing a font-awesome icon. It looks like the image below:

[image]

(Note that the address is a faker generated address. Not a real one :) )

If I change the class of the address div from col-xs-11 to col-xs-10, it looks fine, but then I lose the extra space on the side of the address.

What's weird is that if I remove the font-awesome character from the col-xs-1 div, the alignment is perfect, as expected. But as soon as I add the character back, or any character for that matter, the address wraps underneath the col-xs-1 again.

I have attached the code from my Blade template below. Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening?

```
@foreach ($addresses as $key => $address)
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <strong class="panel-title">{{ $address->name }}</strong><br>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <address>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-11">
                            {{ $address->address1 }}<br>
                            @if ($address->address2)
                                {{ $address->address2 }}<br>
                            @endif
                            {{ $address->city }}, {{ $address->state }} {{ $address->postal_code }}<br>
                            {{ $address->country }}<br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if ($address->email)
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" title="Email"></i> {{ $address->email }}<br>
                    @endif
                    @if ($address->phone)
                        <i class="fa fa-phone" title="Phone"></i> {{ $address->phone }}
                    @endif
                </address>

                <a role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href={{ url("user/address/{$address->id}/edit") }}>Edit</a>
                {!! Form::open(['url' => "user/address/{$address->id}", 'method' => 'delete', 'style' => 'display: inline-block;']) !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['name' => 'delete', 'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @include ('address.index.pagination-clearfix')

@endforeach
```

Comment: This is almost certainly because the col-xs-1 width is being pushed too wide by the icon, so it's not really 1, it's over 1, and 11 won't fit next to it.

Comment: The physical size of that container `col-xs-1` is smaller than the needed size for the font icon to fit, causing it to overflow. Change it to `col-xs-2` and `col-xs-10` problem solved.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that cols of width 1 were too small to fit a character. I think I prefer the look of col-xs-1 and col-xs-10 better, but col-xs-2 and col-xs-10 works well, too.